# How to retrieve full regex match from RE2?

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I'm using RE2 to match a regex on some text but I'm struggling with extracting the result.

What I want is:

Text: "Sample text"
Regex: "p.*x"
Extract the full regex match from the text: "ple tex"

I can't find any function in the RE2 API that supports this. PartialMatch only extracts groups from the regex (marked by parenthesis) but my regexes come from users, I cannot force them to always wrap their regexes in a group. I also don't want to manually wrap each regex in a group because that doesn't sound like an elegant solution and it wouldn't work if the user puts a modifier at the beginning of the regex. This seems like very basic functionality so I'm surprised there is no clear way to do this.

Anyone knows a solution to this?

Comment: It seems you need to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group. `string text; if (RE2::PartialMatch("Sample text", "(p.*x)", &text)) {...}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Although, as I mentioned, I get the regex from the users, so I don't want to wrap it, since they might use modifiers at the beginning of the regex, in which case I would mess up the matching of their original regex (because if I grouped it, then the modifiers would just become part of the regex, I assume, since they wouldn't be at the beginning any more).

Comment: An outer grouping will not affect these inline modifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the whole pattern is a working alternative since the inline modifiers do not have to be at the very beginning of the pattern, and when you add a pair outer parentheses, e.g. to `((?s)go.*there|take.*this)`, the `(?s)` DOTALL modifier will still be applied to both `.` in the pattern.

```
string text; 
if (RE2::PartialMatch("Sample text", "(p.*x)", &text)) {
    // Put more code here  
}
```